# use a model as IEnumerable and static in same view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

Am trying to put together a view where it will generate a detail list from a table through code first and a strongly typed view but also allow the user to input data into through the model into the table.

So the first part is:

```
<table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
                </th>                
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
                    </td>                    
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.GenderID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.GenderID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.GenderID })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
```

The next part to enter a new gender would be:

```
<div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)</div>
                    <div>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "div-form-control", id = "LkUpGender" } })</div>
                    <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</div>
```

The problem is the first part requires:

```
IEnumerable<OrwellFrontEnd.LkUpModels.vwLkUpGender>
```

But the second part seems to not work with that and require:

```
OrwellFrontEnd.LkUpModels.vwLkUpGender
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Create a view model with 2 properties, one for the collection and one for the new object. But since you have links to edit and delete which redirect to other pages, why not a link to create? Alternatively why not use ajax so you can do everything on the same page (where the UI might be something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, some really useful suggestions there.

the links were just left there from the template i was using the the MVC controller generates, they delete and new would be on a separate tree menu link.

I was looking to then use the edit link and Jquery/Ajax to render a new partial page within that partial view but your suggestions seem much better